# Visual studio C# ignores some lines of code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task

Updated:
I have an application that makes a couple of `httpwebrequest`. Therefore I have ran those requests on `Task.Factory.StartNew`. However, what I have found out is that visual studio ignores these lines of `Task.Factory.StartNew` and also ignores the for loop and does not execute them. Also what I have found out is that if I put a break point at the start before creating the tasks and step into these lines code by code the tasks gets created and executed. I have research this online and the possible suggestions that I have found out is to rebuild and clean the solution which I did but it did not help. Also I have changed the application from release to debug mode but none of these have help. can someone suggest a solution my code is as follows:

```
          var list = new List<string>();
           for (var z = 0; z < jobsUrl.Count(); z++)
           {
                                    list.Add(GetSomeData("https://www.example.co.uk" + jobsUrl.ElementAt<HtmlNode>(z).GetAttributeValue("href", "")));
          }
            Task tasks =  Task.Run( ()=> list.ToArray());
             await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the purpose of the `tasks` variable is here.  This is mostly a guess at this time, but it seems more intuitive to me that you'd want to just `await Task.WhenAll(list)`, no?

Comment: Please could you format your code before posting it.

Comment: I did that but visual studio does not execute these lines and also does not throw an exception I only get these tasks created when I debug line by line the code in this way get executed and the tasks gets created

Comment: David is right. You're starting a new task, the list of tasks, these are not awaited. You're only awaiting the task spinup. Not the completion. Its not visual studio causing this: the code is faulty. ... closer inspection: I think the created task doesnt do anything. You're just referencing the list.

Comment: but If I have to await each task to be started there would be no point of using multi tasks that start at the same time how would this be possible in this case

Comment: No, that is not what I am saying: you can await them all at the same time. They are started when you call them. But the only thing you are awaiting is the factory for a task - which takes 0 time.

Comment: Use HttpClient for async, not HttpWebRequest.

Comment: @dai will it make any difference if I use HttpClient eventhought that httpWebRequest provide async methods

Comment: @ghass `HttpWebRequest` does not provide `Task`-based Async methods. The async methods on `HttpWebRequest` use an ancient (and now obsolete) async programming model and are not `await`able (there is an adapter you can use, but it's simpler and easier to use `HttpClient` instead - also, `HttpClient` doesn't throw exceptions for 4xx-5xx response codes.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this doesnt really awaits the list of tasks. Which you also deducted yourself.

```
var tasks = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => list);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Just await the list directly:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list);
```